# How firewall-cmd reads text content

Tags: linux, shell, firewalld

I have a text file with the following content:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
3.3.3.3
4.4.4.4
```

How to extract the content of each line and use it as a variable to allow firewall-cmd to read and write rules

Answer (score 0):

firewall-cmd has flags `--add-entries-from-file` and `--remove-entries-from-file` to read from a text file.

Try something lie

`firewall-cmd --permanent --ipset=xxx --add-entries-from-file=file.txt`